# How to initialize a list of std::vector's values in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

I have a problem with the following code:

```
const std::vector < std::string > arr1 = { "a", "b", "c" };
const std::vector < std::string > arr2 = { "e", "f", "g" };
const std::vector < std::string > globaArr = { arr1, arr2 }; // error
```

I need to initialize globalArr with values: "a", "b", "c", "e", "f", "g" (in one dimension). I don't need to have two-dimensional array.
What do I do wrong?

I can do something like this:

```
globalArr.push_back( arr1 ); // with the for loop inserting each value of arr1
globalArr.push_back( arr2 );
```

but here the globalArr is not const anymore :) I need the same type for all three vectors.

Comment: why don't you just insert a,b,c,d,e,f,g into globalArr?? Idk why you're wasting space by inserting into 2 separate vectors & inserting back into globalArr?

Comment: @Bthegreatest - because it's very uncomfortable if I change values of arr1 or arr2 sometimes and forget to change the same values in globalArr.

Comment: @JavaRunner, so you want to initialize `globalArr` with the values within `arr1` and `arr2`?

Comment: @JavaRunner Ok, then why not initialize `globalArr` with one of the vectors, say `std::vector<std::string> globalArr{arr1};` and then `insert` the other vector with `globalArr.insert(globalArr.end(), arr2.begin(), arr2.end());`

Comment: @Alejandro - because I need three vectors to be the same type :)

Comment: They can all be `std::vector<std::string>`, I don't see the issue here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could implement a function that just sums them. Say, `operator+`:

```
template <class T>
std::vector<T> operator+(std::vector<T> const& lhs,
                         std::vector<T> const& rhs)
{
    auto tmp(lhs);
    tmp.insert(tmp.end(), rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
    return tmp;
}
```

And then just use that:

```
const std::vector<std::string> arr1 = { "a", "b", "c" };
const std::vector<std::string> arr2 = { "e", "f", "g" };
const std::vector<std::string> sum = arr1 + arr2;
```

The function could be named anything, I just picked `+` for simplicity.

Comment: or `concat` as in range-v3, combined with a `to_vector`

Answer (score 2):

In the upcoming [**Ranges TS**](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it will be possible to write the solution by @Barry as

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using namespace ranges;

    const std::vector<std::string> arr1 = { "a", "b", "c" };
    const std::vector<std::string> arr2 = { "e", "f", "g" };
    const auto sum = view::concat(arr1, arr2) | to_vector;

    std::copy(sum.begin(), sum.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ","));
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82625d778fe43bcf)

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is simply put the *elements* of `arr1` and `arr2` into `globaArr`, why not use a for loop?

Example:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < (int)arr1.size(); i++ ) {
    globaArr.push_back(arr1.at(i));
}

for ( int i = 0; i < (int)arr2.size(); i++ ) {
    globaArr.push_back(arr1.at(i));
}
```

Better yet, just write a function that takes in `globaArr` and a vector that you want to add to `globaArr` from. Put the for loop in the function and call the function twice. A little more work, but probably cleaner code.

Comment: Isn't this the same as `globalArr.insert(globalArr.end(), arr1.begin(), arr1.end());` followed by the same for `arr2`?

Comment: Ah, yes. Didn't think of that and didn't see your comment til after I posted. That would work, definitely less code than what I suggested.

Comment: This code is a lot less ugly if you use a ranged-for.

Comment: This is also true.